# Disable "Although this page is encrypted...." in Firefox 14

Tags: security, firefox, selenium, popup

I have been using Selenium RC for automating my test cases. I have stumped across a case wherein a security pop up appears & I am unable to override using either code/ Firefox browser settings.

Pop up Message - "Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party. Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

I have browsed through a lot of solutions posted in this forum & google. Nothing seem to work.
My Browser version is 14.0.1. Most of the solutions available for FF settings are FF 3.0 & older which does not apply.

I have even tried **about:config** & disabled the below set of keys. Doesn't help either.

```
security.warn_entering_secure
security.warn_entering_secure.show_once
security.warn_entering_weak
security.warn_entering_weak.show_once
security.warn_leaving_secure
security.warn_leaving_secure.show_once
security.warn_submit_insecure
security.warn_submit_insecure.show_once
security.warn_viewing_mixed
security.warn_viewing_mixed.show_once
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in your web application which needs to be fixed.

Comment: I guess it's a application error. You can handle the alert box as we do in Webdriver

    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Will suggest upgrade to Selenium-WebDriver for better support.

Comment: I agree with Maitreya, i was unable to disable to disable through FF 14 settings. Finally I had to resort to webdriver alert. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the warning message which says: "Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.  Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?"

Type in "about:config" in your Browser's address box. A caution box will open, just agree to be careful. When the page opens, scroll down to: "security disable_button.OpenCertManager" and double click on it and change it from True to False.  Do the same thing with the one below that:"security disable_button.OpenDeviceManager". Close the page and the annoying and unnecessary warning will not pop-up again.  I just did it, so I know it works.